# How do I hide the default toplink from SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image]

I've been trying to hide the toplink using a script editor, but I can't seem to target to hide the link in the toplinks section. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Why don't you click "EDIT LINKS" and remove the link that way? Or is this not what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: That's a default link created by SharePoint, and you wouldn't be able to delete it by clicking on edit links.

Comment: I can delete it on my side..

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<style>
 #DeltaTopNavigation 
 {
     display :none;
 }
</style>
```

Reference : http://www.macaalay.com/2014/01/28/how-to-remove-sharepoint-2013-quick-launch-andor-top-link-bar/

Comment: Thank you, but what I'm trying to hide is the toplink not the sidebar.

Comment: try this
<style>
#DeltaTopNavigation {display :none}
</style>

Comment: Wow that worked! However, I just want to hide the default toplink.

Comment: what you mean by default toplink ?

Comment: The one that I boxed in red, I'm still planning on using the toplinks. However, SharePoint automatically creates a link on top.

Comment: this is the only solution you can buddy

Comment: No worries. Highly-appreciated.